# updating a text file from a java file

Tags: java, file, file-io, ide

```
public void updateF()throws Exception
{
    int i;
    BufferedWriter outputWriter = null;
    outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(getClass().getResource("valS.txt").getFile()));
    for (i = 0; i < Status.length-1; i++) 
    {
            outputWriter.write(Status[i]+","); 
    }
    outputWriter.write(Status[i]);
    outputWriter.flush();  
    outputWriter.close(); 
}
```

I am trying to update a file "valS.txt" present where all my .java files are present .This code compiles but does not update anything . I think the path is not reachable . HELP!!

Comment: Any errors? exceptions?

Comment: not updating the file :(

Comment: i think this line "getClass().getResource("valS.txt").getFile()" has some problem

Comment: What is `Status[]`?  Where is that populated?

Comment: Are you having your valS.txt in src directory?

Answer (score 1):

outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(valS.txt));

Try that instead of:
outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(getClass().getResource("valS.txt").getFile()));

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Status array is not empty, this code will work but the file text file will be **updated in the compiled/output directory**

So the text file in the source directory will not be updated, but the one in the output directory will.

Also note that the constructor of FileWirter you are using will overwrite the content of the file so you should use the one with the append argument:

```
public FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append) throws IOException
```

**EDIT** : if you REALLY need to update a file in the src directory you could do it like, this.
Not really nice but this will work

```
public void updateF()throws Exception
{

    String fileName = "valS.txt";
    File fileInClasses = new File(getClass().getResource(fileName).getFile());
    System.out.println(fileInClasses.getCanonicalPath());
    File f = fileInClasses;
    boolean outDir = false;

    // let's find the output directory
    while(!outDir){
        f = f.getParentFile();
        outDir = f.getName().equals("out");
    }

    // get the parent one more time
    f = f.getParentFile();

    // from there you should find back your file
    String totoPath = f.getPath()+"/src/com/brol/" + fileName;
    File totoFile = new File(totoPath);

    BufferedWriter outputWriter = null;
    outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(totoFile, true));
    outputWriter.append("test");
    outputWriter.flush();
    outputWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: I don't see another way than hardcoding the path of the file

Answer (score 0):

```
         FileWritter, a character stream to write characters to file. By default, it will 
        replace all the  existing content with new content, however, when you specified a true (boolean)
        value as the second argument in FileWritter constructor, it will keep the existing content and 
        append the new content in the end of the file.
        fout = new FileWriter("filename.txt", true);
        the true is enabling append mode .

write Like:
BufferedWriter outputWriter = null;
outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(getClass().getResource("valS.txt").getFile(),true));
```